# Eclipse Maven Error Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, m2e

I am using Eclipse Juno with Maven 3.0.5 on Windows 7. The project was previously on Windows XP and I have moved to Windows 7 64 bit machine.

I have copied my Eclipse Spring 3, Hibernate 4 and JSF 2.0 project and when I try to compile I am getting the following error

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:2.0.6:process (execution: process, phase: 
generate-sources)
```

I tried as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756431/gwt-maven-error-executing-org-bsc-mavenmaven-processor-plugin2-0-5proces) thread by adding the following in Eclipse.ini file, however it didn't solve the issue.

```
-vm
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Tried building maven install and clean, but problem still persists.

How can I resolve this issue? Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Maven snippet

```
<plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- source output directory -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Have you tried with an updated version of the maven processor plugin (2.2.1 for example) ?

Comment: You probably also changed your eclipse installation. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7392705/367285) answer. I suppose this is the problem and executing mvn from the command line works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions of m2e complain if a Maven plugin does not provide a m2e lifecycle mapping. Newer plugins provider such a mapping via the file *META-INF/m2e/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml* in their JAR. If this file is not present, then Eclipse complains.

It is possible quite down these complaints by adding a lifecycle mapping for older plugins to your POM. In the given example, this mapping is done inside a profile which is automatically activated when a build is running in Eclipse (m2e.version property is set) and it is not active when a regular maven build is done.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>m2e</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>m2e.version</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                      <versionRange>[2.0.6,)</versionRange>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                      <ignore />
                    </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
                </pluginExecutions>
              </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>         
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
  </profile>
```

The example above disables the plugin in Eclipse builds. It is also possible enable it by specifying `<execute />` as action .

Mind that the settings under *pluginExecutionFilter* must match the plugin and the goals of the plugin that you wish to map. Multiple *pluginExecution* elements can be specified to map different plugins.